# Set layout google maps doesn't work with fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I try use google maps in my android app. And two weeks I can't solve my problems: when I add

```java
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //setContentView(R.layout.main); it doesn't work and app stopped,  what to change?
    SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();


    }
```

My XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
      <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
       </fragment>
       </LinearLayout>
```

my logs, i have this error:

```
   04-22 03:28:33.858      318-433/? E/libEGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent:671 error 3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
   04-22 03:28:34.038  29219-29219/com.example.messmap E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4745)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
        at com.example.messmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-22 03:28:34.048      318-433/? E/libEGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent:671 error 3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
   04-22 03:28:35.269     853-1397/? E/Process﹕ Error getting pid for '0'
   04-22 03:28:35.610  29352-29352/? E/ru.ivi.framework.utils.L﹕ onCreate (logMemory:237 03:28:35.622)
   04-22 03:28:35.690  25607-25607/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.example.messmap.MetricaContentProvider
   04-22 03:28:35.710  25607-29406/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.example.messmap.YPLContentProvider
   04-22 03:28:40.514      437-437/? E/Parcel﹕ Reading a NULL string not supported here.
   04-22 03:28:40.514      437-437/? E/Parcel﹕ Reading a NULL string not supported here.
```

If anybody had this problems, help please. What problems with fragment? I tried to to use MapFragment, but it was without result too

Comment: Is Google Play Services library included in your project?

Comment: Yes, google play services , support v4 and permissions in manifest

Comment: How about in project properties or gradle?

Comment: Follow [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) to include Google Play Services library to your project.

Comment: Project properties: Google API 4.0.3 debug via USB, device number 4.3

Comment: I checked it, google play service works

Comment: Add your manifest also. Your Log shows problem with your google play services only. Which IDE are you using? Make sure you are following all steps without any change

Comment: You should look at the samples for something similar to what you want and code it exactly like the sample.